# Insert Data in first empty row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Hello Guys**
I have a Sheets that has multipe separte tables on 1 page. Here is the Page. 
[image]

Now i want to get the last row of one of those groups. 
I used this Code to write text in the last row of a sheets where the is only 1 Table on 1 Page.

```
opt2.getRange(opt2.getLastRow()+1, 2, 1, 1).setValue(keyword);
opt2.getRange(opt2.getLastRow()+0, 3, 1, 1).setValue(volume);
```

opt2 is the name of the Page
i tried setting the range to a new Value.

```
var tab1 = opt2.getRange("B:D");
opt2.getRange(tab1.getLastRow()+1, 2, 1, 1).setValue(keyword);
opt2.getRange(tab1.getLastRow()+0, 3, 1, 1).setValue(volume);
```

But this also didnt work any ideas on how to do it ?
Thx for the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use multiple importrange with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279729/use-multiple-importrange-with-different-length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using .getLastRow() you can check the first free cell in a column by creating a helper function, that takes a sheetobject and a column number as parameters.

```js
function findFirstFreeRow(sheet, colNum) {
    var v = sheet.getRange(1, colNum, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(),
        l = v.length,
        r;
    while (l > 0) {
        if (v[l] && v[l][0].toString().length > 0) {
            r = (l + 2);
            break;
        } else {
            l--;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Then, in your code call the function to compute the row number that has the first free cell in that column.

```
opt2.getRange(findFirstFreeRow(opt2, 2), 2, 1, 1).setValue(keyword);
opt2.getRange(findFirstFreeRow(opt2, 3), 3, 1, 1).setValue(volume);
```

Note: when there are no 'gaps' inside the column you can also try

```
var lastRow = opt2.getRange("B:B").getValues().filter(String).length + 1;
```